# Which tag is used to change the website name/URL in Google's Index?

Tags: google-search, meta-tags, technical-seo

See the image below, GREEN is what I want to achieve and RED is what it shows now:

[image]

I tried to use:

`<meta property="og:site_name" content="something something" />`

But it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a few sites, Google uses a portion of the title. It discards  parts of it, depending on characters such as dash, brackets, and pipe.

But it tries not to be fooled. The title has to have relevance to your text.

On the competitors site, its using the `og` tag

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Park Ride Fly">
```

Your site has none of these.  My suggestion is to remove the colon from your title and add at least the following `og` tags

- url
- title
- site_name
- description

You also have 11 errors in your html.  And 28 in your css. It always helps to clean these up.  Otherwise Google may not be able interpret your site properly.

Comment: in my case it shows selectairportparking.com where as in below site it shows Park Ride FLY   how can i add spaces there? like green highlighted text so that my text become Select Airport Parking instead of selectairportparking.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that any information in the markup is a recommendation for the search engine, and not a rule. When he sees that you have become a "brand", then you will get the proper result.
Build links with a brand key and look at the result.